# How to implement a SignalR client in Delphi

Tags: delphi, signalr, signalr.client

I look like having a requirement to access a SignalR hub with a Delphi client.

How do I implement a basic SignalR client in Delphi?

More generally, where can I find an up to date description of the protocol?

Traffic load will not be high, so it doesn't have to be extremely clever or anything.

[Edited to make it less of a "recommendation" question.]

Comment: This is a recommendation question, and so is off topic here

Comment: I've been working on [WebSocket support in xxm](https://github.com/stijnsanders/xxm/tree/master/Delphi/demo2/13%20WebSockets) I'm not sure if it's straight-forward to use it to connect to SignalR endpoints.

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: First,I disagree that it is a "recommendation" question - I need to know how to do something, and similar questions have been asked and not answered. Second, how would you phrase it so as to NOT be a :"recommendation question"?

Comment: You said "Is there a component out there that already supports this?" which made it a slam dunk recommendation question. You then replaced that with "More generally, where can I find an up to date description of the protocol?" Which is also slam dunk recommendation question.

Comment: Then how should I have phrased it?

Comment: There isn't any way to phrase it. It's a recommendation question. Your answer even contains another recommendation question. This is the wrong site for such questions. You should ask somewhere more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer to question: I found useful, low level version of the documentation in a legacy zip of version 1.3
It has since vanished from the signalr git repository, and I've been unable to find a newer version online anywhere.

I have popped it here for convenience.

http://www.mithril.com.au/SignalR%20Protocol.docx

This document describes the protocol at a suitably low-level for me to feel confident I can construct a partial implementation of SignalR using existing components, sufficient for my purposes anyway.
If a more up to date version of this exists anywhere, I'd appreciate a link.